# Upcoming events listing with date on custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, web, custom-post-type

i want to display list of events with dates upcoming order (ex: 1. 23 March, 2013, 2. 30 March, 2013). Below is the query I'm using to filter out posts from my database:

```
query_posts( 'post_type=myevents&meta_key=_datepicker&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC&showposts=20');
```

This is not working, with this query i got my events listed in the following order:

07 April, 2013, 18 April, 2013, 19 June, 2013 , 20 October, 2013, 23 March 2013, 24 March 2013

Events happening in March are being listed at last. No order at the start too.

I'm using a custom field to store event date & the date format of it's as 23-Mar-2013, but I'm showing the front end dates in 23 March 2013 format.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are ordering by the

**07** April, 2013, **18** April, 2013, **19** June, 2013 , **20** October, 2013, **23** March 2013, **24** March 2013

since your orderby=meta_value is not setup to account for actual "dates" it will never sort properly.  You will need to account for the Date, Month, & Year if you want to sort this out properly.  The following reference might help you accomplish what you want.

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Example_4